# Siesta Framework Request Cancellation

Tags: ios, swift, siesta-swift

I could not find any way to cancel a request using [Siesta Framework](https://github.com/bustoutsolutions/siesta). Is this possible, and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that there is a method `cancel()`, which should be called on the `Request` object. As documented, it is not guaranteed to really cancel the request if it is already started, but it will at least ignore the result and send you a completion/failure, which you can then handle accordingly.

Example:

```
let siestaRequest = MyAPI.profile.request(.post, json: ["foo": [1,2,3]])
// when needed, later
siestaRequest.cancel()
```

Comment: Note that _no_ network framework can guarantee that a request will be cancelled if it’s already started. Once packets have started going to the server, you’re in race condition territory and all guarantees are off.

Comment: @PaulCantrell, thanks for the clarification. I did not mean the answer to sound like a complaint. I was looking for the cancellation method as I could not find an example. Since I found it in the classes of the library, I just wanted to write it down.

Comment: No offense taken. Just wanted to note the general need for caution when making assumptions about cancelled network requests.